# Can we show app "maintenance/services disabled" pop up from play store developer account?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-services, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

In an ionic4 hybrid mobile application.
We want to show a "Maintenance message" pop-up on our mobile application launch. Can we configure this kind of message from play store developer account?

This popup should appear like the pop-up we see for any update notification for an app.
In the sample image below, how to configure the pop-up content and action?

We are very new to mobile application development, any inputs around this will really help us.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure it from the play store developer console.

What you see obove is the [In-App updates feature of the play-core library](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates). If you want exactly that, you would need to implement the library and use the provided `AppUpdateManager` which helps you handle updates, showing the dialog and so on.
Allthough I don't know if you can easily use the library with Ionic4.

You can also implement the solution yourself. Make an API call to your server and send the current app-version. Your server can then send back update information and tell your app if a new version is available. In your app you can then decide to show a dialog and guide the user to the play store.